# Why are so many warnings coming up when compiling my bison file?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I am working on designing a lexical and syntax analyzer for a simple programming language. Here is my flex .l file:

```
%{
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
#include "littleDuck.tab.h" 
int line_num = 1;
%}
id      [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
cteI    [0-9]+
not     (<)(>)
cteF    {cteI}(\.{cteI}((e|E)("+"|"-")?{cteI})?)?
ctestring   (\".*\")

%%

[ \t]   ;
program {return PROGRAM;}
var     {return VAR;}
print   {return PRINT;}
"else"  {return ELSE;}
"if"    {return IF;}
{id}    {return ID;}
\=      {return '=';}
\<      {return '<';}
\>      {return '>';}
{not}   {return NOT;}
\+      {return '+';}
\-      {return '-';}
\/      {return '/';}
\*      {return '*';}
\:      {return ':';}
\,      {return ',';}
\;      {return ';';}
\{      {return '{';}
\}      {return '}';}
\(      {return '(';}
\)      {return ')';}
{cteI}  {yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return INT;}
{cteF}  {yylval.fval = atof(yytext); return FLOAT;}
{ctestring} {yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return STRING;}
\n      {++line_num;}
.       ;

%%
```

This file is being compiled correctly by flex, although I'm not completely sure if I can summarize some terms. My real problem comes when compiling my bison file. I am doing it from a Ubuntu terminal by entering this:

```
gabriel@virtualbox:~/Lenguajes/flexBison$ bison -d littleDuck.y
```

It returns 22 nonterminals useless in grammar and 41 rules useless in grammar. My bison file is the next:

```
%{
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int yylex();
extern "C" int yyparse();
extern "C" FILE *yyin;
extern int line_num;

void yyerror(const char *s);
%}

%union{
    int ival;
    float fval;
    char *sval;
}

%token ID NOT PROGRAM VAR PRINT IF ELSE

%token <ival> INT
%token <fval> FLOAT
%token <sval> STRING


%%
programa:
    PROGRAM ID ':' vars_1
    ;
vars_1:
    VAR
    ;
vars:
    VAR ID id_1
    ;
id_1:   
    ',' id_1
    | ':' tipo tipo_1
    ;
tipo:
    INT
    | FLOAT
    ;
tipo_1:
    /* empty */
    ID id_1
    ;
bloque:
    '{' e1
    ;
e1:
    estatuto e2
    | e2
    ;
e2:
    estatuto e2
    | '}'
    ;
estatuto:
    asignacion
    | condicion
    | escritura
    ;
asignacion:
    ID '=' expresion ';'
    ;
expresion:
    exp exp_1
    ;
exp:
    termino exp_2
    ;
exp_1:
    /* empty */
    | '>' exp
    | '<' exp
    |NOT exp
    ;
exp_2:
    '+' exp
    | '-' exp
    ;
escritura:
    PRINT '(' esc_1
    ;
esc_1:
    expresion esc_2
    | STRING esc_2
    ;
esc_2:
    ',' esc_1
    | ')' ';'
    ;
condicion:
    IF '(' expresion ')' bloque cond
    ;
cond:
    ';'
    | ELSE bloque ';'
    ;
termino:
    factor term
    ;
term:
    '*' termino
    | '/' termino
    ;
var_cte:
    ID
    | INT
    | FLOAT
    ;
factor:
    '(' expresion ')'
    | var_cte
    | '+' var_cte
    | '-' var_cte
    ;

%%
main() {
    FILE *myfile = fopen("testFile", "r");
    if (!myfile) {
        cout << "I can't open file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    yyin = myfile;

    do {
        yyparse();
    } while (!feof(yyin));

}

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    cout << "Yikes! Parse error on line " << line_num << "! Message: " << s << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
```

Why are warnings being generated and how can I get rid of them? Sorry for posting complete programs, but I think all information is important as flex file shows what tokens are being generated and bison file has all grammar rules.

Comment: might help to show some of the errors

Comment: littleDuck.y: warning: 22 nonterminals useless in grammar
littleDuck.y: warning: 41 rules useless in grammar
littleDuck.y:34.1-4: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: vars
littleDuck.y:35.16-19: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: id_1
littleDuck.y:39.15-18: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: tipo
Those are some of the errors. Almost all of them are the same, with the argument changing every time.

Comment: If they are useless, remove them. If you actually need to use them, then there are mistakes in your grammar.

Comment: You are not using `vars` and that whole tree becomes useless.

Comment: In `tipo_1:
    /* empty */
    ID id_1
    ;`, the `empty` comment isn't accurate, or you are missing the `|` separating the empty option from `ID id_1`.  This isn't the cause of your current problem — I think @leppie nailed that.  But it is likely a mistake.

Comment: I had not noticed I missed the pipe. Also, I had not completed vars_1 grammar and also not noticed. Still I am not sure why some of them are classified as useless, for example estatuto leads to 3 syntax variables, I cannot find any ambiguity or reason why it would be useless.

Comment: @gabrielbaca: it's useless because it cannot be derived from the start production (programa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar is essentially just:

```
programa:
    PROGRAM ID ':' vars_1
    ;
vars_1:
    VAR
    ;
```

which means that the only valid program it will accept is

```
program id : var
```

where `id` might be any valid identifier.  Anything else will be a syntax error.

All the rest of the rules are unreachable and useless, as there is no way to reach them from `programa`.  So bison is telling you that you might as well just delete them.

What you probably want is to add some other `programa` or `vars_1` rule that leads to the rest of the rules so as to actually parse the language you want

Answer (score -1):

Some grammar was indeed incorrect or with missing symbols. I rewrote my grammar and it worked correctly, only pointing out there were 3 shift-reduce. I added left associativity to tokens doing the next:

```
%left '*' '/'
%left '+' '-'
```

Also I did not add a token for reserved words "int" and "float", only having those for int and float constants. This was obviously a huge problem, as I could not declare any variable. I added them and replaced the token for constants with FLOATC and INTC. This was added on lexical file as well as grammar file.